# Implementing HTTP Digest Auth for Django view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I need to implement a view in Django that requests digest auth instead of basic auth. The authentication should not be linked to the default User class but instead to a custom model.

I tried with [django-digest](https://bitbucket.org/akoha/django-digest/overview) but it is outdated and not usable with recent versions of Django (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.importlib').

I need a very simple digest auth solution for my Django application.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to "solve" this by leaving auth to the reverse proxy and use REMOTE_USER in my app. This approach works very well.